# JPQL how to define BigInteger constants

Tags: jpa, jpql, jpa-2.1

In a JPQL query I compare a numeric constant to a bind parameter of type BigInteger `(:param = 1)`. Is there any way to define that the constant type is a BigInteger in order to avoid IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Could you please show your current code, including how you query the database with JPQL, and specify _exactly_ what problem you have?

Comment: as of jpa2.0 you cannot define TYPE in JPQL itself, but you should pass the same type as that you have used for variable param in Entity

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
:param = java.math.BigInteger.ONE
```